# How to replace NA values with the nearest observed value in a time series in R

Tags: r

I've a dataset which ID specific CR values occur in a time series.

```
ID  Encounter   Time    CR
1   1   8/11/16 3:00 PM NA
1   1   8/12/16 12:00 AM    1
1   1   8/12/16 7:00 AM NA
1   1   8/12/16 9:00 AM 1.2
1   1   8/15/16 7:00 AM 0.9
1   2   3/21/17 3:00 PM NA
1   2   3/22/16 12:00 AM    0.7
1   2   3/22/16 3:00 AM NA
1   2   3/22/16 9:00 AM 1.1
1   2   3/23/16 7:00 AM NA
```

I want to group the IDs by their Encounter and want to replace NA values for CR with the nearest one. So, the program should replace a NA CR values either from up or down based on the lowest Time difference. I want an output like:

```
ID  Encounter   Time    CR
1   1   8/11/16 3:00 PM 1
1   1   8/12/16 12:00 AM    1
1   1   8/12/16 7:00 AM 1.2
1   1   8/12/16 9:00 AM 1.2
1   1   8/15/16 7:00 AM 0.9
1   2   3/21/17 3:00 PM 0.7
1   2   3/22/16 12:00 AM    0.7
1   2   3/22/16 3:00 AM 0.7
1   2   3/22/16 9:00 AM 1.1
1   2   3/23/16 7:00 AM 1.1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the clue is `na.locf` from `zoo` grouped by 'ID', 'Encounter'.  `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(ID, Encounter) %>% mutate(CR = na.locf(na.locf(CR, na.rm=FALSE), fromLast = TRUE))`

Comment: The same `na.locf` function is also present in the `imputeTS` package, as well as the `spacetime` package.